# Python "module 'fileName' has no attribute 'functionName'"

Tags: python

I have a `main.py` file accessing a number of other modules.

I want to call the function using `fileName.fileFunction()`

In the module I want to access, I am importing the `main.py` file and the code is as follows:

```
import main
def fileFunction():
    statements
    statements
    var = input("enter a name")
    statements 
    return var
```

I want to access the value the user enters into var and then use that in my main module but I get the following error:

```
module 'fileName' has no attribute 'fileFunction'
```

Comment: Are you importing filename into the main.py file?

Answer (score 0):

In your main file you called **fileName.fileFunction()**
and in your fileName you imported main.

While executing the fileName module your main file will execute first in which you have **fileFunction()** which is not defined.

import the fileName module in your main and remove import main line from the fileName module.

**Main.py**

```
import fileName
print(fileName.fileFunction())
```

**fileName.py**

```
def fileFunction():
  a=input("Enter a name : ")
  return a
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got it backwards.

**fileName.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def fileFunction():
    var = print("enter a name")
    return var
```

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fileName

fileName.fileFunction()
```

**command**:

```
$ python main.py
enter a name
```

Answer (score 0):

you try to do like this ?

**file_name.py**

```
def file_function():
    retunrn 'file_name'
```

**main.py**

```
from file_name import file_function
```

**your_file.py**

```
import main
print(main.file_function())
```